# Pandas Ser.agg Behaving Like Ser.apply

Tags: python, pandas

I created a function that I expect would aggregate the series to a single number. However, it is as if the method apply is called instead of aggregate.

```py
import pandas as pd

def f(x): return 1

ser = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
ser.agg([f])
```

I expected it to return the scalar (integer) 1, but it returned `pd.Series([1,1,1,1,1])`.

My hypothesis is my user-defined function (UDF) has some incompatibilities with the aggregate method. What I understand is that the UDF takes pd.Series as input and outputs a scalar.

I read the documentation on Series.agg and the UDF must be able to be passed a pd.Series or be passed to Series.apply method. However, I don't understand when the UDF is passed to apply or when a series is passed to the UDF.

Comment: So you expect it to print 5 but it prints 15?

Comment: @Sebastian sorry I forgot to input the expected output and the current output. Edited

Comment: what do you exactly want to compute ?  the average ? ie.  from that given series, what are you expecting back ?

Comment: @D.L in my actual case, I have a DataFrame of many y_preds and a Series of y_true. I would like to compute a score (sklearn ROC AUC Score) of the y_preds to the y_true, grouped by whether the observation is part of training, validation, or testing set. My idea is to create a UDF that passes y_true to the sklearn function, but it doesn't produce a number for every group and column.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ser.apply(f)` is tried first and only if that fails is `f(ser)` called.
[This is a bug in Pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/53325) and seems to have been deprecated in 2.1.

In this example, part of the problem is that `f` isn't really performing an aggregation, that is, it's not using any of `ser`'s methods or looping over `ser`.
So as a workaround, you could add an assertion of sorts, that `x` is iterable:

```
def g(x):
    # Workaround to trick Pandas into thinking we're doing an
    # actual aggregation.
    iter(x)
    return 1
```

```
>>> ser.agg([g])
g    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: I need 15 reputations to cast an upvote, but I definitely would've upvoted your answer if I could :). In my case, I found that I cannot pass a list of UDFs to agg if I also pass args/kwargs. I manually pass each function then concat the resulting dfs as of now.